# Integral of $\int^1_0 \frac{dx}{1+e^{2x}}$

Tags: integration

I am trying to solve this integral and I need your suggestions.
I think about taking $1+e^{2x}$ and setting it as $t$, but I don't know how to continue now.

$$\int^1_0 \frac{dx}{1+e^{2x}}$$
Thanks!

Comment: Multiply the numerator and the denominator by $e^{-2x}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the change of variable $u=e^{x}$, you get
$$
\int_{[0,1]}\frac{dx}{1+e^{2x}} = \int_{[1,e]}\frac{1}{u(1+u^2)}du
$$

Comment: Then expand in partial fraction, and it's ok.

Comment: how its $u^2$ ?

Comment: What do you mean? ($e^{2x}=(e^{x})^2=u^2$, if that's what you ask)

Comment: @Clement C. after I get $\frac{1}{u(1+u^2)}du$ how I solve it with partial fraction?

Comment: By writing it as a sum of (easy to integrate) fractions, and integrating each of them independently.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Putting $e^{2x}=v\implies 2x=\ln v\implies 2dx=\frac{dv}v$

$$\int^1_0 \frac{dx}{1+e^{2x}}=\int_1^{ e^2}\frac1{2v(1+v)}dv=\frac12\cdot\int_1^{ e^2}\left(\frac1v-\frac1{v+1}\right)dv $$

Answer (score 1):

$\int^{1}_{0}\frac{dx}{1+e^{2x}}=$ $ \int^{1}_{0}\frac{e^{-2x}dx}{1+e^{-2x}}=$ $-\frac{1}{2}\int^{1}_{0}\frac{(1+e^{-2x})'dx}{1+e^{-2x}}=$
$=-\frac{1}{2}ln(1+e^{-2x})|^{1}_{0}= \frac{1}{2}ln\frac{2e^{2}}{1+e^{2}}$