# Improper Integral Question $ \int^{\infty}_0 \frac{\mathrm dx}{1+e^{2x}}$

Tags: improper-integrals

I want to check if it's improper integral or not 
$$ \int^{\infty}_0 \frac{\mathrm dx}{1+e^{2x}}.$$
What I did so far is : 
set $t=e^{x} \rightarrow \mathrm dt=e^x\mathrm dx \rightarrow \frac{\mathrm dt}{t}=dx
$ so the new integral is:
 $$ \int^{\infty}_0 \frac{\mathrm dt}{t(1+t^2)} =  \int^{\infty}_0 \frac{\mathrm dt}{t}-\frac{\mathrm dt}{1+t^{2}}$$
now how I calculate the improper integral, I need to right the $F(x)$ of this integral and then to check the limit?
Thanks!

Comment: You are correct. So the integral of 1/t is a standard result, log(t), and then to integrate 1/(1+t^2) think about making a tan substitution.

Comment: Perhaps you mean "improper integral" = "אינטגרל לא-אמיתי" ?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391257/integral-of-int1-0-fracdx1e2x/391335#391335

Comment: You need to change the integration boundaries. Also, there is an error in the partial fractions step. The original integral is convergent, and your answer should be a finite number.

Comment: You have to change the limits of integration to be  
$$\int_1^\infty\cdots$$

Comment: @Riad but the next integral its defined in 1 - $\frac{1}{1+t^2}$ just the first one not.

Comment: The integral is improper. If you just need to determine if the integral converges,  you can use the comparison test  ($0<{1\over 1+e^{2x}}<{1\over e^{2x}}$) to show it is convergent.

Comment: $t$ should be from 1 to $\infty$. Check the definition of improper integrals. This is one type of them.

Comment: Yes, it feels like you are misusing the term "improper" to mean "not converging." This integral is improper because it has $\infty$ as one if its bounds. What you are asking is, "Does it converge, and if so, what does it converge to?"

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes I saw it now, I wrote it in my paper but here something else. thanks. I changed it now.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392140/integrating-int-frac11exdx-partial-fractions/392163#392163

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You made a couple of mistakes. Firstly, you forgot to change the limits of the integration, so your integral is actually $\displaystyle\int_1^\infty \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{t(1+t^2)}$. Furthermore, $\frac{1}{t(1+t^2)} \neq \frac{1}{t}-\frac{1}{1+t^2}$. Rather $\frac{1}{t(1+t^2)} = \frac{1}{t}-\frac{t}{1+t^2}$.

Hence your integral becomes $\displaystyle\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{t}-\frac{t}{1+t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t = \left[\log(t)-\frac{1}{2}\log(1+t^2)\right]_1^\infty = \left[\frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{t^2}{1+t^2}\right)\right]_1^\infty$
$$ = \frac{1}{2}\left[\log(1)-\log\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right] = \frac{1}{2}\log(2).$$

Comment: I guess this was homework?

Comment: I know why you are changing $0 \rightarrow 1$ but where the values between 0 to 1 goes?

Comment: I'm not changing $0$ into $1$. It's just that $e^0 = 1$ and $e^\infty = \infty$. Hence if $x\in[0,\infty)$, then $t\in[1,\infty)$.

Comment: Ok, I got it, now I write the F(x) then I evaluate the limit between 0 to $\infty$ of him?

Comment: Indeed. ${{{}}}$

Comment: This is what I get: $$\lim_{b \to \infty}ln|t|-\frac{1}{2}ln|1+t^2|$$ and all this between 0 to $b$ after evaluating it I get $ln(0)$ in one of the expressions

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: so how to calculate it? after set the values : $$(ln|b|-\frac{1}{2}ln|1+b^2|)-(ln|0|-\frac{1}{2}ln|1|)$$ there is and error there, or I write its a not improper integral.

Comment: The lower end of integration is $t=1$, not $t=0$ remember? Also, it might be convenient to write $\ln |b| - \frac{1}{2}\ln|1+b^2| = \frac{1}{2}\ln\left|\frac{b^2}{1+b^2}\right|$.

Comment: yes, thank you, but it still no improper integral. you helped me to understand few things!

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

First, it must be

$$\frac1{t(1+t^2)}=\frac1t-\frac t{1+t^2}\;\;,\;\;\text{then}:$$

$$\int\limits_1^\infty\left(\frac1 t-\frac t{1+t^2}\right)dt:=\lim_{b\to\infty}\left(\log\frac b{\sqrt{1+b^2}}+\log\sqrt 2\right)$$

Comment: There is no arctan in the antiderivative. The OP made an algebra error after the substitution step..

Comment: True, I relied on what he wrote. Thanks

Comment: Where is the algebra error? this is what you get if you will make partial fraction substitution

Comment: No Offir, check it carefully.

Comment: The bounds also need to change with the change of variables. And I don't think that notation $\lim_{b\to\infty,\epsilon\to 0}$ is particularly clear, since the expression does not include either $b$ or $\epsilon$.

Comment: I just realized there was *also* a mistake with the lower bound...and the downvoter rushed in. Oh, well.

Comment: I see it now, I changed it, I wrote it fine on my paper but here something else.thanks.

Comment: Dear Don, people in glass houses. I seem to get random downvotes on old questions of mine *every* time I comment negatively on one of your answers. Either you have a stalking defender, or you are personally punitively downvoting other users.

Comment: Good you realize that, @ThomasAndrews: either you "forget" stuff or else these are your first, and most probably not the last, times you "get" what many (I'd say "most") of us get from time to time: serial downvoters (and sometimes: just downvoters). Take care.

Comment: I don't mind random downvotes, I just note that in the last few months, almost all of the random downvotes I've gotten, without comment, come after I've commented on one of your posts.

Comment: Incidentally, was that an admission to punitive downvoting, @DonAntonio?

Comment: Apparently you didn't even understand what I wrote, @ThomasAndrews, but don't worry and do what I do: don't care about points. They aren't money and they don't give you happiness. :)

Comment: Was just trying to understand the phrase "Good you realize that." It wasn't clear what you were suggesting I realized. I don't know why I get downvoted when I comment negatively on your posts, but I do know it happens. Punative downvoting is not the same as serial downvoting - a single downvote can be punative, but it isn't serial and won't be caught automatically by the system.

Comment: And you most definitely care about points, or you wouldn't have complained above that people were downvoting your *wrong answer.* (I removed my downvote when you fixed it, by the way.)

Comment: Oh, I see...so *you* did downvote the answer? And about complaining: I wonder what were you doing when you wrote your "Dear Don" comment...

Comment: Either you have a short memory, or you don't recall complaining, "I just realized there was also a mistake with the lower bound...and the downvoter rushed in. Oh, well." BTW, I never said I didn't downvote. I downvoted it because, after your first edit, it  was still wrong, and if you had made any effort, you'd have seen that your error was already covered in comments to the question. (When my first error is trusting the work of the OP, I tend to re-read the question and comments,  when I edit.)  @DonAntonio

Comment: Had you had some patience, you could have either asked or waited until it was clear the mistakes stem from following what the OP wrote. Not a justification, just an explanation: he both had wrong the partial fraction development and the integral's lower limit. Once this was mentioned by someone else *and I had the opportunity to note that* the due corrections were made. You though rushed to downvote. Well, it's your privilege, I guess...as is anyone else's.

Answer (score 0):

Does this solution make sense too?

Let   $\displaystyle t=1+e^{2x},$   $x\in(0,\infty), t\in(2,\infty)$

So    $\displaystyle dx = \frac{1}{2(t-1)}dt$,

Then,

$\displaystyle\int^{\infty}_0\frac{1}{1+e^{2x}}dx$

$\displaystyle= \frac{1}{2}\int^{\infty}_2\frac{1}{t(t-1)}dt$ 
  (Please pay attention to the changing interval)

$\displaystyle= \frac{1}{2}\int^{\infty}_2(\frac{1}{t-1} - \frac{1}{t})dt$

$\displaystyle= \frac{1}{2}\left(\left[\ln{\left(t-1\right)}\right]_2^{\infty} - \left[\ln{t}\right]_2^{\infty}\right)$

$\displaystyle= \frac{1}{2}\lim_{t\to\infty}\ln{(t-1)} - \frac{1}{2}\lim_{t\to\infty}\ln{t} + \frac{1}{2}\ln{2}$

$\displaystyle= \frac{1}{2}\lim_{t\to\infty}\ln{\frac{t-1}{t}} + \frac{1}{2}\ln{2}$

$\displaystyle= \frac{1}{2}\ln{2}$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{d x}{1+e^{2 x}} &=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-2 x}}{e^{-2 x}+1} d x \\
&=-\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{d\left(e^{-2 x}+1\right)}{e^{-2 x}+1} \\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\left[\ln \left(e^{-2 x}+1\right)\right]_{0}^{\infty} \\
&=\frac{1}{2} \ln 2
\end{aligned}
$$